# Android (оплата товара)

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Моя цель: создать интернет-магазин android, но после нескольких запросов в гугл а так и не добился успеха. Как мне встроить оплату через Visa/MasterCard в android app. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

По скольку вы ничего не написали о том, что у вас есть и как у вас формируются заказы, то ответ будет таким же - общим.

Для начала вам нужно получить ссылку на 3D Secure банка эмитента для оплаты. Ссылка эта уникальна для каждой оплаты и содержит она к примеру некий orderId. То есть вы неким образом формируете корзину в вашем приложении. Отправляете эти данные на ВАШ сервер, далее ВАШ сервер по запросу в банк "открывает" в нем окно для оплаты и вам возвращает ссылку на это "окно" в приложение. Далее вы в приложении открываете эту ссылку в вашем WebView и покупатель увидит стандартную форму ввода оплаты интернет покупки (3D Secure)

Я могу ошибаться с точки зрения как должно быть реализовано это на сервере. Но на клиенте вы всего лишь должны получить ссылку на 3D Secure от вашего сервера и скормить эту ссылку WebView

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать покупки внутри приложения через [In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html). Для этого в консоли разработчика для конкретного приложения необходимо будет добавлять товары, который можно купить в нем. Через In-app Billing можно будет оплачивать картой Visa/Mastercard.

Также можно воспользоваться сервисами, позволяющими организовать прием платежей с помощью банковских карт, через терминал и т.д., например: [Робокасса](https://www.robokassa.ru/ru/), [Яндекс.Касса](https://kassa.yandex.ru/).

Но это будет сложнее, чем реализовать In-app Billing внутри приложения.